# Renew Certificate in Oracle Enterprise Cloud Control OMS Manager Console

Tags: oracle, certificate, oracle-enterprise-manager, wallet

Environment:

- Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 13.4
- OMS console with third party certificate
- Secured

My situation is the following:

1. I am new in this client and apparently the former DBA added a third party certificate in the OMS console, which is near to expire.
2. I've been reading the documentation but I can't find the keystore or the wallet associated to this certificate.

So far, I checked the following

```
[oracle@hcbae2p01ora022 bin]$ $OMS_HOME/bin/emctl status oms -details
Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 13c Release 4
Copyright (c) 1996, 2020 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Enter Enterprise Manager Root (SYSMAN) Password :
Console Server Host        : hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp
HTTP Console Port          : 7788
HTTPS Console Port         : 7803
HTTP Upload Port           : 4889
HTTPS Upload Port          : 4903
EM Instance Home           : /u01/app/oracle_em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1
OMS Log Directory Location : /u01/app/oracle_em/gc_inst/em/EMGC_OMS1/sysman/log
OMS is not configured with SLB or virtual hostname
Agent Upload is locked.
OMS Console is locked.
Active CA ID: 1
Console URL: https://hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp:7803/em
Upload URL: https://hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp:4903/empbs/upload

WLS Domain Information
Domain Name            : GCDomain
Admin Server Host      : hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp
Admin Server HTTPS Port: 7102
Admin Server is RUNNING

Oracle Management Server Information
Managed Server Instance Name: EMGC_OMS1
Oracle Management Server Instance Host: hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp
WebTier is Up
Oracle Management Server is Up
JVMD Engine is Up

BI Publisher Server Information
BI Publisher Managed Server Name: BIP
BI Publisher Server is Up

BI Publisher HTTP Managed Server Port   : 9701
BI Publisher HTTPS Managed Server Port  : 9803
BI Publisher HTTP OHS Port              : 9788
BI Publisher HTTPS OHS Port             : 9851
BI Publisher is locked.
BI Publisher Server named 'BIP' running at URL: https://hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp:9851/xmlpserver/servlet/home
BI Publisher Server Logs: /u01/app/oracle_em/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/BIP/logs/
BI Publisher Log        : /u01/app/oracle_em/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain/servers/BIP/logs/bipublisher/bipublisher.log
```

As you can see for the information above, the console is secured in port 7803. I thought that the certificates should be stored in a wallet, but I can't find the wallet anywhere. I neither was able to find any command in `emctl` or in `emcli` that can show me where this certificate is stored.

What I know is that the certificate is there, as I used the `secdiag` option of `emctl`

```
[oracle@hcbae2p01ora022 bin]$ $OMS_HOME/bin/emctl secdiag openurl -url https://hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp:7803/em
Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 13c Release 4
Copyright (c) 1996, 2020 Oracle Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Log file: /tmp/OpenPage_2023_02_21_13_45_115472876152891123503.log

Opening page: https://hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp:7803/em
Using non-validating trust manager; all certificates will be blindly accepted.
Proxy server is not set
Using protocol: TLSv1

Negotiated protocol: TLSv1

Getting the certificate chain

Details of cert# 1 in chain:
Subject: EMAILADDRESS=xxxxxxx, CN=hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp, OU=xxxxxxx, O=xxxxxxxxxx, L=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ST=xxxxxxxx, C=xx
Issuer: CN=XXXXX CA, DC=cloud, DC=corp
Valid from: Tue Mar 23 13:54:18 UTC 2021
Valid till: Thu Mar 23 13:54:18 UTC 2023
Serial#: 914345119400343461451536535824392411922746991
Public key: Sun RSA public key, 2048 bits
  modulus: 231855705770066152570314131577369954637603242446759578989206803754751294824351565914129743732110994827544588460966543883605976172129693569117661509357921588815183478850378089638600314229871995314771805178017341640817875936605315833364302707372595554647453833532393376815757155001416722179412428142624866504902792330046510191621551136336433918248638504659645288726326144907300691458403587891238454297424723893811783631933359920866785373444400398845738032568684675766778615996191586165668755883030522959798859689120112193205210100146390085495955132802650583693008692078856106184239283369895227655357520072938286
  public exponent: 65537
Signature algorithm: SHA256withRSA

Following headers are present in the response:
Date : Tue, 21 Feb 2023 13:45:12 GMT
Vary : Accept-Encoding
Adf-Context-Id : fd3875f9-7da2-4e9a-bbe1-cdbc60ba6af8-00000002
X-Frame-Options : sameorigin
X-ORCL-EMOA : true
X-ORACLE-DMS-RID : 0:3:1
X-Content-Type-Options : nosniff, nosniff
X-XSS-Protection : 1; mode=block, 1; mode=block
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID : fd3875f9-7da2-4e9a-bbe1-cdbc60ba6af8-00000002
Adf-View-Id : %2Flogon%2Fcore-uifwk-console-login
Content-Type : text/html;charset=UTF-8
Cache-Control : no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, max-age=0


Response saved at :
/tmp/hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp_7803_2023_02_21_13_45_134697786630783685089.html
[oracle@hcbae2p01ora022 bin]$
```

As you can see above, the certificate that allows me to access by `https` to the OMS console is stored somehow in OMS. But I can't find where exactly. I have tried to check all wallets in the server, but I could not find anything.

I'd like to know how can I update this certificate with a new one that I have already in my hands. Is there a way to identify whether this certificate was included using `emctl secure createca` ? if so, how can I update the certificate stored there ?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @Balazs Papp, I was able to find the wallet used by the OMS Console

```
[oracle@hcbae2p01ora022 console]$ pwd
/u01/app/oracle_em/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/ohs1/keystores/console
[oracle@hcbae2p01ora022 console]$ orapki wallet display -wallet `pwd`
Oracle PKI Tool Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.4.0.0.0
Copyright (c) 2004, 2020, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Requested Certificates:
User Certificates:
Subject:        EMAIL=xxxxxxxxxxxxx,CN=hcbae2p01ora022.hcbe.corp,OU=xxxxxx,O=xxxxxx,L=xxxxxxxxx,ST=xxx,C=xx
Trusted Certificates:
[oracle@hcbae2p01ora022 console]$
```

What I don't get is why it does not appear as a Trusted certificate ? If I copy this wallet to a different location, then I can use `orapki` to import the new certificate into the wallet, and then use `emctl secure console -wallet` to renew the certificate ?

I have read somewhere that if there is a change in the certificate, such as the email address, you have to do it from scratch. Is that so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wallet used by OMS has a fixed location: `<WEBTIER INST HOME>/config/OHS/ohs?/keystores/console/`.

In your case it should be under `/u01/app/oracle_em/gc_inst/user_projects/domains/GCDomain/config/fmwconfig/components/OHS/instances/ohs1/keystores/console`.

This is NOT the wallet that was used for configuration. That was another wallet used for storing the certificates temporarily, and the actual configuration step imported those to the wallet above.

The wallet that was used for configuration could be anywhere on the filesystem, there is no reference to it, maybe you can find it in bash history.

Now you can copy this wallet, import the new certificates in the copied wallet, then use that copied wallet as parameter of `emctl secure console -wallet` for renewing the certificates.

If you are unsure, you can revert to a self signed certificate, after which you can start over from the initial state:

```
emctl secure console -self_signed
emctl stop oms -all -force
emctl start oms
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was able to find the wallet you were mentioning.  Now, I can copy the wallet to a different location and using `orapki` to import the certificate. However, see my updated question, because the certificate does not appear as such.

Answer (score 1):

Another way when using official CA and certificate signed by CA.

Here are steps to secure OEM console using https(tls):

- Certificate has to be converted into pkcs12 format.
- Then imported into auto-login wallet and then imported into OEM.
- `emctl` will reconfigure Weblogic by its own.

Note: Certain version of orapki do not support `import_pkcs12`, the one shipped with agent(13.15) or database(19.x) does, the one shipped with WLS does not.

```
mkdir cert
cd cert
orapki
 Oracle PKI Tool : Version 12.2.1.4.0

orapki wallet create -wallet . -auto_login
orapki wallet add -wallet . -trusted_cert -cert root.ca.pem -pwd ...
```

Convert cert and key from pem into pkcs12 format:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey cert.key -in cert.pem -out cert.p12

orapki wallet import_pkcs12 -wallet . -pkcs12file cert.p12
orapki wallet display -wallet .
```

Import new certs to EM, emcli should store new certificates in WLS

```
emctl secure console -wallet .
emctl stop oms -all -force
emctl start oms
```

PS: There are also commands
"`emctl secure wls`" to install certificate into Weblogic console.
"`emctl secure oms`" to install certificate for communication with agents.
Combining these commands is quite dangerous.
have to executed in exact order otherwise OEM won't start anymore.